# How do I make a $\sigma$ the same size as an uppercase $\sum$ with a symbol or letter in the center of the hole of the $\sigma$?

Tags: math-operators

I am a bit too new to figure out how to simultaneously make something that looks like this:

```
\sum_a^b
```

but instead is a lowercase `\sigma` that has been enlarged so that I can write a little letter inside it.

Essentially I want what's on the left in this image with the normal sigma summation sign to the right for reference as to the size of it.

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The blackness of the symbol is not fully satisfying, but here's a possible solution:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\sigmaop}[1]{\mathop{\mathpalette\@sigmaop{#1}}\slimits@}
\newcommand{\@sigmaop}[2]{%
  \vphantom{\sum}%
  \sbox\z@{$\m@th#1\sum$}%
  \dimen@=\ht\z@ \advance\dimen@\dp\z@
  \dimen\tw@=\wd\z@
  \ifx#1\displaystyle\dimen@=.9\dimen@\fi
  \ooalign{%
    \hidewidth
    $\vcenter{\hbox{$\m@th#1#2$\kern.3\dimen\tw@}%
     \ifx#1\scriptstyle\kern-.25ex\fi}$\hidewidth\cr
    $\vcenter{\hbox{%
      \resizebox{!}{\dimen@}{$\m@th\sigma$}%
    }\ifx#1\scriptstyle\kern-.25ex\fi}$\cr
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\[
\sigmaop{s}_{i=1}^n \sum_{i=1}^n
\textstyle \sigmaop{s}\limits_{i=1}^n \sum\limits_{i=1}^n
\scriptstyle \sigmaop{s}\limits_{i=1}^n \sum\limits_{i=1}^n
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Some possible refinements, in particular the inner symbol is slightly moved down and it is in script style when the symbol is used in text style.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\sigmaop}[1]{\mathop{\mathpalette\@sigmaop{#1}}\slimits@}
\newcommand{\@sigmaop}[2]{%
  \vphantom{\sum}%
  \sbox\z@{$\m@th#1\sum$}%
  \dimen@=\ht\z@ \advance\dimen@\dp\z@
  \dimen\tw@=\wd\z@
  \ifx#1\displaystyle\dimen@=.9\dimen@\fi
  \ooalign{%
    \hidewidth
    $\vcenter{%
     \vspace{.1\dimen@}%
     \hbox{$\m@th\@demotestyle#1#2$\kern.3\dimen\tw@}%
     \ifx#1\scriptstyle\kern-.25ex\fi}$\hidewidth\cr
    $\vcenter{\hbox{%
      \resizebox{!}{\dimen@}{$\m@th\sigma$}%
    }\ifx#1\scriptstyle\kern-.25ex\fi}$\cr
  }%
}
\newcommand\@demotestyle[1]{%
  \ifx#1\displaystyle
  \else
    \ifx#1\textstyle
      \scriptstyle
    \else
      \scriptscriptstyle
    \fi
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\[
\sigmaop{s}_{i=1}^n \sum_{i=1}^n
\textstyle \sigmaop{s}\limits_{i=1}^n \sum\limits_{i=1}^n
\scriptstyle \sigmaop{s}\limits_{i=1}^n \sum\limits_{i=1}^n
\]
\[
\sigmaop{t}_{i=1}^n \sum_{i=1}^n
\textstyle \sigmaop{t}\limits_{i=1}^n \sum\limits_{i=1}^n
\scriptstyle \sigmaop{t}\limits_{i=1}^n \sum\limits_{i=1}^n
\]
\[
\sigmaop{g}_{i=1}^n \sum_{i=1}^n
\textstyle \sigmaop{g}\limits_{i=1}^n \sum\limits_{i=1}^n
\scriptstyle \sigmaop{g}\limits_{i=1}^n \sum\limits_{i=1}^n
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\resizebox{!}{\dimen@}{\Huge$\m@th\sigma$}` would reduce the blackness at least a little bit.

Comment: @Manuel I tried it, but as the `cmsy` font is available only at maximum size of 10pt, there's no gain.

Comment: @Manuel No difference at all.

Comment: @Manuel Yes, I see a tiny difference in positioning; in the picture, the red symbol is built with `\Huge`: [picture](http://i.stack.imgur.com/LRJjt.png) The blackness doesn't change.

Comment: This is great, exactly what I was looking for, I wasn't sure that such a thing as I was asking could even be done!

Comment: wouldn't you want the internal "s" scaled similarly in all three instances?  the largest version looks okay by itself, but if more than one size is used, the difference is a bit too striking for my taste.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Your remarks were something I was thinking about before going to the dentist. Is the new version better?

Comment: better?  yes!  i particularly like the example with the *g*.  thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Here's an alternative that perhaps provides a more natural syntax.  I define `\foo` as an operator in which `\sigma` is scaled to the same vertical extent as `\sum`.  Note that `\foo` operates without any inset lettering.  Then I define an auxiliary macro `\fooinset{inset}` if one wishes an inset a letter inside of `\foo`.  The way I've defined it, normal sub and superscripting (using `_` and `^`) can be added seamlessly to either `\foo` or `\fooinset{}`, in any math style.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\stackMath
\DeclareMathOperator*{\foo}{\scalerel*{\sigma}{\sum}}
\newsavebox{\foobox}
\newcommand\fooinset[1]{\ThisStyle{\savebox\foobox{$\SavedStyle\foo$}%
  \stackinset{c}{-.11\wd\foobox}{c}{-.5\LMpt}{%
  \scaleto{#1}{.6\ht\foobox}}{\phantom{\SavedStyle\foo}}\kern-\wd\foobox\!}\foo}
\begin{document}
\[
\foo_{i=3}^{6}(f^2(i))
\]
\centering This is inline: \(\foo_{i=3}^{6}(f^2(i)) \)
\[
\fooinset{s}_{i=1}^n x\quad
\textstyle\fooinset{t}_{i=1}^n x\quad
\scriptstyle\fooinset{g}_{i=1}^n x\quad
\scriptscriptstyle\fooinset{s}_{i=1}^n x\quad
\]
\[
\sum_{i=1}^n x\quad
\textstyle\sum_{i=1}^n x\quad
\scriptstyle\sum_{i=1}^n x\quad
\scriptscriptstyle\sum_{i=1}^n x\quad
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

One can even do stuff as versatile as this:

```
\[
\fooinset{\frac{x+y}{y}}_{i=1}^n x_i
\]
```

[image]